# Shaitan messes with my thoughts

Tags: shaitan

While I was reading the Qur'an, I started having thoughts I do not want to think of, but still do. 
Like really bad stuff, for example

```
Allah is shit (tövbe)
Qur'an is shit (tövbe)
```

I'm sorry, I don't mean to think this, and I don't believe it, but I keep saying tövbe. I'm going to cry. I don't want to think that. I feel so bad.
Why is it like this all of a sudden? Help me, please. I don't want this.
Is shaitan messing with my thoughts?
It has to be shaitan.
I feel so bad, I don't want to think it, because I feel like Allah isn't going to forgive me.